# Get the response using ngResource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I created a factory where I have a method forming the object 'create' and the controller causes through submit REST command. Now I would like a response data because the console I can see that the request was successful. How to do it ? How to get the response? I would add that for me it numeral 32.

```
app.factory('Claims', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/portal/rest/registerClaim', null,
            {
                'create': { method: 'POST' }
            });
        }]);

app.controller('ClaimCtrl', ['$scope', 'Claims', function($scope, Claims) {

        $scope.registerClaim = function (PIN) {
            console.log(PIN);
            var obj = {
                    "t":t,
                    "a":"t",
                    "b":"z",
                    "c":"x",
                    "d":"q"
            };
            var a= Claims.create(obj);
            console.log(a);

        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

methods of ngResource is asynchronous, so you can get response using $promise

you can read this document about $resource.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

I changed your code in here.

```
app.factory('Claims', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/portal/rest/registerClaim', null,
        {
            'create': { method: 'POST' }
        });
    }]);

app.controller('ClaimCtrl', ['$scope', 'Claims', function($scope, Claims) {

    $scope.registerClaim = function (PIN) {
        console.log(PIN);
        var obj = {
                "t":t,
                "a":"t",
                "b":"z",
                "c":"x",
                "d":"q"
        };
        Claims.create(obj).$promise.then(function(resp) {
          $scope.resp = resp;
        });

    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. But I have a problem so the answer is not to parse as it receives a response like "13": "0", "14": "1" and I would just text eg. 12.

Comment: all of the response in the resp variable, I think you can console.log(resp) and find it at browser.

Comment: Ok, I know but the response is in the form of {"0":"3","1":"2"} and would like to convert it to text as such. 32

Comment: you means JSON.stringify(obj)?

Comment: No, such solution has not worked. Do you have other ideas?